# Why top command shows different results depending on sort mode

Tags: centos, top, lxd

When used with -o%CPU:

```
PID   USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM   TIME+   COMMAND
58641 mysql     20   0   26.9g  17.0g  21108 S  5800 13.5   2890:39 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr
29703 apache    39  19  640196 107232  25412 S 100.0  0.1   0:00.85 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
28925 apache    39  19 1254240  98100  33792 S 100.0  0.1   0:08.38 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
29214 apache    39  19  654744  46536  34464 S 100.0  0.0   0:01.51 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
29138 apache    39  19 1110388  49732  36088 S 100.0  0.0   0:07.20 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
29702 apache    39  19  576596  44824  26136 S 100.0  0.0   0:00.92 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

When used with -oPID:

```
PID   USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM   TIME+   COMMAND
58641 mysql     20   0   26.9g  17.0g  21108 S   5.0 13.5   2890:47 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr
29703 apache    39  19  654152  44480  33096 S   1.0  0.0   0:01.25 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
28925 apache    39  19 1221472  47340  33792 R   0.0  0.0   0:08.46 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
29214 apache    39  19  656452  46124  34464 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.65 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
29138 apache    39  19 1126740  64956  36088 S   3.0  0.0   0:07.37 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
29702 apache    39  19  570516  40312  29444 R   1.0  0.0   0:01.16 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

Always shows 0%..5% not more for the same PIDs. Centos 7 on LXD.

Comment: Is it possible that the second time you check those processes actually consumed less CPU?... The memory consumption of those processes was also decreased. Notice the "TIME+" column (Total CPU time the task has used since it started) has hardly changed.